# What is best way to validate the max length in XSD for alphanumeric fields?

Tags: xml, validation, types, xsd, maxlength

I need to validate the max length of alphanumeric data in an XML document using XSD schema.  If I use restriction base xs:string, I end up with validation errors on type because it contains numbers.  Is there a better way to do this?

Each field in the XML I am validating has a different field length I am checking for.  The only ones I am getting false errors on are those with mixed numbers and characters which are expected for those particular fields.  I need to check max length because if they exceed the length it won't persist in the database and I want to know when that happens with an error message.

Any suggestions or thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: Set up a pattern with the regular expression `[A-Za-z0-9]{1,12}`. I have used ASCII letters only but instead of them the regular expression language used in XSD with Unicode character classes is pretty powerful to support other letters (e.g. `\p{L}` for all Unicode letters) as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting validation errors on alphanumeric data then you are doing something wrong, but it's not possible to know what you are doing wrong without knowing what you are doing: show us some code and we'll tell you where you went wrong.

Certainly a restriction of an `xs:string` type using a maxLength facet will not restrict the content of the string in any way except for its length.